# Printing 20 values of ARGV[]i get this output please explain why?

Tags: c++, c

When i print argv value 20 times i get output like the one shown below why is it ? please explain

```
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
       printf("%s\n",argv[i]);
}
```

output:

```
 ./a.out a

 a

 ./a.out

 a

 (null)

 SHELL=/bin/sh

 TERM=xterm-color

 USER=root

 SUDO_USER=hari

 SUDO_UID=501

 SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/launch-Jm4kQ0/Listeners

 __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x0:0:0

 USERNAME=root

 PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Applications/gedit.app:/Users/hari/Downloads/gradle-1.9/bin:/usr/X11/bin
 PWD=/Users/hari/Desktop/Cerner/Pointer
 SHLVL=1
 SUDO_COMMAND=/usr/bin/su
 HOME=/var/root
 LOGNAME=root
 LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
 SUDO_GID=20
 DISPLAY=/tmp/launch-DMwOKd/:0
```

Comment: Behaviour when reading beyond `argv[argc]` is undefined.  Anything could happen.  Your system appears to print out environment variables; others may crash.

Comment: Congrats you encountered an **Undefined Behavior** !

Comment: argc has a reason to exist... in C arrays bound checking is responsability of programmer. And you have better to learn it for stack overflow question, hitting an Undefined Behavior for C is rewarded quasi-automatically with -1 ... Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You experienced undefined behavior: you are only allowed to access `argv[0]`...`argv[argc]` where the last entry is a null pointer. From the looks of it, the environment is stored right after the array for `argv` but there is no such guaranteed at all.